# Issues with Batch Scripts for automated .cpp usage

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, new-operator

I am currently working on a batch file automatically compiles and excecutes a source file and shows the excecution time. I just don't believe the shown excecution times and don't know how to test them. It would mean the world to me if anyone could help me avoid potential bugs and give me tips for improving. I am quite new to coding, so excuse me if I am talking complete nonsense at any point.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd TeamCode\src\main\cpp\sources
mkdir ..\exec   2>nul

rem Compile the C++ program
gcc -o ..\exec\jpgtest.exe jpg_usage_example.cpp sdk\jpgengine.cpp Position.cpp -lstdc++
if !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ   0 (
    echo Compilation failed. Stopping...
    exit /b !ERRORLEVEL!
)

cd ..\exec

rem Record the start time
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/:. " %%a in ("!DATE! !TIME!") do (
    set "start=%%c-%%b-%%aT%%d:%%e:%%f"
)

rem Run the compiled program
start "" jpgtest.exe

rem Wait for the process to finish
:waitLoop
tasklist | findstr /i "jpgtest.exe" > nul && (
    rem Process is still running, wait for 1 millisecond and check again
    timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
    goto :waitLoop
) || (
    rem Process has finished, record the end time
    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/:. " %%a in ("%DATE% %TIME%") do (
        set "end=%%c-%%b-%%aT%%d:%%e:%%f"
    )
    goto :calculateTime
)

:calculateTime
rem Calculate the execution time using PowerShell
powershell -Command "$start = Get-Date; $end = Get-Date; (New-TimeSpan -Start $start -End $end).TotalSeconds" > temp.txt
set /p elapsedTime=<temp.txt
del temp.txt

echo Execution Time: %elapsedTime% seconds

endlocal
```

I was expecting longer excecution times. `Execution Time: 0.0040356 seconds`  doesn't seem right for saving an image.

Comment: Hard to say, really. Could be that the program's done and written the file to a RAM buffer in the filesystem that the filesystem and OS promise will make it's way to permanent storage at some point in the near future.

Comment: Depends on the size of the image and the drive you have, but 4 milliseconds don't seem unreasonable to me. For 4MB image you only need 1GB/s drive speed (easy with SSD drive).

Comment: The StackExchange network has a site specifically for code review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `timeout /t 1` does not "wait for 1 millisecond", it waits for up to 1 second. Technically it waits for one second, unless a key is pressed before that time has elapsed. If you open a Command Prompt window, type `%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key, it may prove useful in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was tagged with [powershell] and the posted code uses PowerShell. Now it has been removed. There is a possibility that your quality of life could improve if this was all done using PowerShell. This is not tested, but might be something that does or could be made to work.

```
Set-Location -Path TeamCode\src\main\cpp\sources
New-Item -Path ..\exec -ItemType Directory | Out-Null

# Compile the C++ program
gcc -o ..\exec\jpgtest.exe jpg_usage_example.cpp sdk\jpgengine.cpp Position.cpp -lstdc++
if (0 -ne $LASTEXITCODE) {
    Write-Error 'Compilation failed. Stopping...'
    exit
}

# Run the compiled program
$RunTime = Measure-Command -Expression { ..\exec\jpgtest.exe }

Write-Host "Execution Time: $RunTime"
```